# How to render threaded comments in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

If my API call returns the following json:

```
[
  {
    "postId": 1,
    "parent": 0,
    "text": "This is parent Comment 1",
    "user": "user1@example.com"
  },
  {
    "postId": 2,
    "parent": 0,
    "text": "This is parent Comment 2",
    "user": "user2@example.com"
  },
  {
    "postId": 3,
    "parent": 1,
    "text": "This is child comment 1 for postId 1",
    "user": "user3@example.com"
  },
  {
    "postId": 4,
    "parent": 2,
    "text": "This is child comment 1 for postId 2",
    "user": "user4@example.com"
  },
  {
    "postId": 5,
    "parent": 1,
    "text": "This is child comment 2 for postId 1",
    "user": "user5@example.com"
  }
]
```

And I'm using a `fetch` call to store the data in the `state` comments:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
      comments: []
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchComments();
}

fetchComments(){
    fetch('https://myApiUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                comments: responseJson
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            Alert.alert("Unable to fetch data. No Internet");
        });
 }
```

I'm using `FlatList` to show the comments:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.comments}
    renderItem={
        ({item}) => 

            <View>
                <Text> {item.user} </Text>
                <Text> {item.text} </Text>
            </View>

    }
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
/>
```

All the comments appear fine in the `FlatList`. How would I show the child comments below the parent comment?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work with a FlatList:

1. Render a new FlatList in the renderItem, if the comment has parent comments.
2. In the first renderItem function, if the comment is a child comment, skip that, do not render it.
3. Fix row height somehow if this method skews it.

If this doesn't work, I would recommend using something else than FlatList, and transform your comments data to a proper hierarchy.